# Create Visualiser for audio recording Android

Tags: android, media-player, android-canvas, audio-recording

So basically I have created a page with a visualiser and a button for recording the audio. I want the visualiser to run for the audio that I am recording. I guess I need to get the MaxAmplitude for the recording and then dynamically plot a visualiser graph for every small period. Can someone please help me with that ? or if there is a better way to do it. Currently the code i pasted, the visualiser runs for the recording after recording it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private static final float VISUALIZER_HEIGHT_DIP = 200f;

MediaPlayer mp;

private Visualizer mVisualizer;

private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
private VisualizerView mVisualizerView;
private TextView mStatusTextView;
private File metapath;
private static String[] META_PATH;
private Button play;
private boolean mStartRecording;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
private static String mFileName = null;

private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mStatusTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.recording);

if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) 
        || Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY))
        metapath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);

META_PATH = metapath.list(new WavFilter());

mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.subscreen);

play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startandstop);

mStartRecording=true;
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onRecord(mStartRecording);
        if (mStartRecording) {
            play.setText("Stop recording");
        } else {
            play.setText("Start recording");
        }
        mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
    }
});

setupVisualizerFxAndUI();        
       mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);

mStatusTextView.setText("Playing audio...");
}


private void onRecord(boolean start) {
if (start) {
    startRecording();
} else {
    stopRecording();
}
}

private void startRecording() {
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(metapath.getPath()+"/myfile.3gp");
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

try {
    mRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
}

mRecorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
mRecorder.stop();
mRecorder.release();
mRecorder = null;
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    mPlayer.setDataSource(metapath.getPath()+"/myfile.3gp");
    mPlayer.prepare();
    mPlayer.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
}
}

class WavFilter implements FilenameFilter {
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".wav"));
}
}

private void setupVisualizerFxAndUI() {

mVisualizerView = new VisualizerView(this);
mVisualizerView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        600,
        (int)(VISUALIZER_HEIGHT_DIP * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));

mLinearLayout.addView(mVisualizerView);
mLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

mVisualizer = new Visualizer(0);
mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
    public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
            int samplingRate) {
        for(int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++)
            bytes[i]+=2;
        mVisualizerView.updateVisualizer(bytes);
    }

    public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {}
}, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false); 
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();

if (isFinishing() && mp != null) {
    mVisualizer.release();
    mp.release();
    mp = null;
}
}

class VisualizerView extends View {
private byte[] mBytes;
private float[] mPoints;
private Rect mRect = new Rect();

private Paint mForePaint = new Paint();

public VisualizerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mBytes = null;

    mForePaint.setStrokeWidth(6f);//set width of the moving wave
    mForePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mForePaint.setColor(Color.RED);//color of the moving wavd\e
}

public void updateVisualizer(byte[] bytes) {
    mBytes = bytes;
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (mBytes == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mPoints == null || mPoints.length < mBytes.length * 4) {
        mPoints = new float[mBytes.length * 4];
    }

    mRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    for (int i = 0; i < mBytes.length - 1; i++) {
        mPoints[i * 4] = mRect.width() * i / (mBytes.length - 1);
        mPoints[i * 4 + 1] = mRect.height() / 2
                + ((byte) (mBytes[i] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2) / 128;
        mPoints[i * 4 + 2] = mRect.width() * (i + 1) / (mBytes.length - 1);
        mPoints[i * 4 + 3] = mRect.height() / 2
                + ((byte) (mBytes[i + 1] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2) / 128;
    }
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawLines(mPoints, mForePaint);
}
}

}
```